# How to integrate qextserialport 1.2win alpha with Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qextserialport

i need to communicate with a serial RS232 device using a GUI in Qt....i downloaded the latest code from [code google...](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/downloads/detail?name=qextserialport.1.2win-alpha2.zip&can=1&q=)...but donno what to do next...initialy i did (i dont remember which version of qextserial it was) but it had a .pri file which i just included in my .pro file...[this website...](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/wiki/QextSerialPort_1_2_Beta2)...but now there is no .pri file in the downloaded code..

```
include(qextserialport/src/qextserialport.pri)
```

Please help me any one who have integrated this feature to Qt Creator...thanx in advance

Comment: Which version did you download? 1.2 beta or 1.2 RC?

Comment: Here's a list of releases, I suggest downloading the one released on March 18th http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/downloads/list?can=1&q=

Comment: To be safe (even though this is crappy coding), use the full path in your include in the PRO like so: `include(C:/rotating_image/QExtSerialPort/src/qextserialport.pri)`

Comment: @Louis93 1.2 win-alpha2 [here...](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/downloads/detail?name=qextserialport.1.2win-alpha2.zip&can=1&q=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you're using the 1.2 Alpha version which does not have a PRI include file, using the recommended version found [here](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/downloads/list?can=1&q=) or any version after the 1.2 Alpha will have a PRI include fine and should work fine.